# VBA: How to use a variable as an argument in range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace the argument in a Range with a variable so I can call a sub with different variable.

Example:

```
sub calc(i, j As String)
 .range(i:j)
end sub

sub main()
 calc A1, B23
end sub
```

I want the final result in this case to be

```
.Range("A1:B23")
```

But I keep getting errors.
Example code which gets an error:
subscript out of range in:

```
If DatePart("y", Date) > DatePart("y", Sheets(s).Range(x).Value) Then
```

s & x are declared as Strings
Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test and try understanding the next approach:

```
Sub checDateParts()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = rngCalc(sh, "A1", "B23")
 MsgBox rng.Address        'returned the created range address
 Set rng = rngCalc(sh, "A1")
 If IsDate(rng.Value) Then 'check if the value of "A1" cell is date
    MsgBox DatePart("y", Date) > DatePart("y", rng.Value)
 Else
    MsgBox "The value of cell """ & rng.Address & """ is not a date..."
 End If
End Sub

Function rngCalc(sh As Worksheet, i As String, Optional j As String) As Range
    If j <> "" Then
        Set rngCalc = sh.Range(i & ":" & j)
    Else
        Set rngCalc = sh.Range(i)
    End If
End Function
```

You cannot directly compare a date (today date) with a range containing more cells. You can previously extract the maximum date of the range and make the comparison with this one:

```
Sub checDatePartsBis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, maxDate As Date
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = rngCalc(sh, "A1", "B11")
 MsgBox rng.Address        'returned the created range address
 
 maxDate = DateValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), "dd.mm.yyyy")) ': Stop
 MsgBox "Maximum date in the processed range is """ & maxDate & """ and " & vbCrLf & _
        "And today is """ & Date & """."
 If DatePart("y", Date) > DatePart("y", maxDate) Then
    MsgBox "Yes, it is..."
 Else
    MsgBox "No, it is not..."
 End If
End Sub
```

You must understand that using `DatePart("y", Date)` returns the day of the year. If you need/want comparing the years, you should use DatePart("yyyy", Date).

Please, test the above solution and send some feedback.

Comment: and what about a single variable?
I am still getting an error in this line :
If DatePart("y", Date) > DatePart("y", Sheets(s).Range(x).Value) Then

Comment: @Mihael Manolov: What connection do you see between your question and what you are asking now? Do you see here any concatenation? I do  not understand anything regarding your need. This is, anyhow, **a different question** expressed in a not appropriate way. You did not say anything about this problem, where the problem is, what data are you trying comparing, if receive an error, if yes, what error, if not what does return against what you need. Anything... This community has some rules but you do not try, at least, respecting anything.

Comment: @Mihael Manolov:  Does the above code answer your question?

Comment: I though I have error because of false syntax, so I asked the question with the most complicated scenario in my code, but I can't tell if ti fixes the error because I get the error of the first row in my code which in my case is with 1 variable. I have tested my code with hardcoding (to test the logic) and it works well. So I believe the error is because of bad syntax, but I cant be sure. This is the long answer. The short answer would be - Maybe

Comment: @Mihael Manolov: You did not explain what you want accomplishing. Should I understood that you want to compare **years** or **days of the year**? Then, are you sure that the range you try testing returns a date? . But you cannot check a single date with a range (containing more cells) value... You firstly must learn asking a question! So, what do you try doing with that line of code? Can you explain (in words)? Your code line does not say too much to us... I will try posting a general code, based only on my imagination, to make you understand what is it about. I (only) hope that...

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation!!
I partly solved the problem replacing the arguments from "calc A1, B23" to "calc "A1", "B23"" (just adding quotes) but your comment helped me a lot!

Comment: @Mihael Manolov: Glad I could help!